# Bulk 301 redirects removing multiple languages from a store

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to do a lot of 301 redirects on an eCommerce site; I have 4 stores that are going down to 1.  So for each url on the site there are 4 instances

```
http://tld.com/default/xyz.html
http://tld.com/german/xyz.html
```

plus 2 more languages that are formatted the same

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tld\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tld\.com$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^default(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^spanish(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^french(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^german(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^products\/browse\-by\-industry\/food\-service\.html$ "https\:\/\/tld\/products\/browse\-by\-industry\/manufacturing\/food\-beverage" [R=301,L]
```

No luck.  Is there a way to do this in the .htaccess file or am I writing 4 301's for each url on the old site?  Rewrite engine is on

Comment: Your RewriteConds demand that the REQUEST_URI starts with one of those language names, but then your following RewriteRule tries to match on something that _starts_ with `products` – that doesn’t make sense.

Comment: And why use RewriteConds here anyway – why not just one RewriteRule on its own, that uses a pattern with alternation at the beginning? `RewriteRule ^(default|spanish|…)/something$ https://example.com/foobar`

Comment: And btw. the _substitution_ part is not a regular expression, so “escaping” characters in there does not make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tld\.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(default|spanish|german|french)/ [NC]  
 RewriteRule ^/?[^/]*(.*)  $1 [R=301,L]
```